# When realloc, the existing and newly inserted data contain strange values

Tags: arrays, c, memory

The dynamic memory takes the initial size input, then automatically increases it when it fills up, and then new data is entered.
If you check the values in the array, there are strange values.

```
int main() {
    BOOK *books = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    int size = -1;
    menu(books, size, count);
    return 0;
}



void menu(BOOK *books, int size, int count) {

    printf("input initial size.\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    books = allocArray(size);
    if (books == NULL) {
       return;
    }
    while (1) {
        printf("========menu========\n");
        printf("1. input book data\n");
        printf("2. books\n");
        int selector = -1;
        scanf("%d", &selector);
        switch (selector) {
            case 1:
                inputBook(books, &count, &size);
                break;
            case 2:
                showAllBooks(books, count);
                break;
            default:
                free(books);
                books = NULL;
                return;
        }
   }
}

void inputBook(BOOK *books, int *count, int *size) {
    if (*count == *size) {
        printf("--------realloc +5\n");
        *size = *size * 5;
        books = reAllocArray(books, *size);

    }
    printf("--------input--------\n");
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    printf("title :");
    scanf("%s", books[*count].title);

    printf("author :");
    scanf("%s", books[*count].author);

    printf("price :");
    scanf("%d", &books[*count].price);
    *count = *count + 1;

    }

BOOK *allocArray(int size) {
    BOOK *books = NULL;
    books = (BOOK *) malloc(sizeof(BOOK) * size);
    if (books == NULL) {
    printf("malloc fail\n");
    } else {
        memset(books, 0, sizeof(BOOK) * size);
    }
    return books;
}

BOOK *reAllocArray(BOOK *books, int size) {
    BOOK *temp = (BOOK *) realloc(books, sizeof(BOOK) * size);
    if (temp == NULL) {
    printf("realloc fail\n");
    }
    return temp;
}

void showAllBooks(BOOK *books, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        printf("%d. title: %s author: %s proce: %d\n", i + 1, books[i].title, books[i].author, books[i].price);
    }
}
```

When the initial size is set to 1, then 1, 1, 1 data is input and additional data is input.
realloc happens and I input 2, 2, 2
If you check the array, it contains 1,1,1 and null, null, and 0.

If more data is previously entered, the existing data may also be damaged.

Comment: `inputBook` changes the `books`  parameter locally, but the caller cannot see the change. You need to return the new value (like in `reAllocArray`) or use a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: The menu has a selection 1 and 2.  The switch has cases 1 and 5

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks, new value is returned, so it works well.

Comment: These tutorial links may help explain the difference between passing function arguments by value and by reference: [Call by Value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_value.htm) [Call by Reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thanks a lot, it was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `inputBook`, the value of `books` may changed inside the function to point to a reallocated memory block:

```
        books = reAllocArray(books, *size);
```

However, that does not change the corresponding `books` variable in `menu` because function parameters in C are passed by value. (OP must already be aware of that since they are using pointers for the other parameters of `inputBook`.)

For consistency with the other parameters of `inputBook`, I recommend change the type of the `books` parameter to `BOOK **` and changing `menu` to pass the address of its `books` variable as it does for `count` and `size`:

(in `menu`):

```
                inputBook(&books, &count, &size);
```

```
void inputBook(BOOK **pbooks, int *count, int *size) {
    BOOK *books = *pbooks;
    if (*count == *size) {
        printf("--------realloc +5\n");
        *size = *size * 5;
        books = reAllocArray(books, *size);
        *pbooks = books;
    }
    printf("--------input--------\n");
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    printf("title :");
    scanf("%s", books[*count].title);

    printf("author :");
    scanf("%s", books[*count].author);

    printf("price :");
    scanf("%d", &books[*count].price);
    *count = *count + 1;

    }
```